# Eclipse PDE - How to sort the Properties in the Standard Propeties view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse 3.6 plugin, and have a view that contains a `TreeViewer`. 
When an item from this `TreeViewer` is selected, its properties appear in the standard Properties View. The Properties currently are ordered alphabetically by default.

 I would like to order these properties *differently*.

It seems like someone else has had this problem too:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/393029/

> The properties in the Properties view of the default generated editor
>   is  sorted by alphabetical order. I would like to ask how to modify
>   and  arrange them in different orders.

The suggested solution is:

> Your editor needs to provide the PropertySheetPage from the 
>   getAdapter(Class) method. If it doesn't provide one the property sheet
>   will use the default PropertySheetPage, which uses the standard
>   collator  to produce the sort order. Your getAdapter() method needs to
>   provide a  specialized subclass of PropertySheetPage that sets you
>   sorter instead.

So I need to subclass [PropertySheetPage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/class-use/PropertySheetPage.html), override the `setSorter` method and everything should be fine.

Two questions arise:

1. Why does it write in the documentation that:

   > This class may be instantiated; it is not intended to be subclassed.
2. Where do I make the link between the Standard Properties View and the subclass of the `PropertySheetPage`?

   I am not using an editor in my case, but just have a `TreeViewer` that when an item is selected it provides the properties.

   Any support is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing and found a solution.

What I did is add a sort sequence prefix to the id of the property pages I was contributing (basically a 3 digit number) and create a [ContributionComparator](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/model/ContributionComparator.html) that took the first 3 digits of the id and do a basic sort.

The code looks something like this:

```
@Override
public int compare(IComparableContribution c1,
        IComparableContribution c2) {

    int result = super.compare(c1, c2);

    IPluginContribution pc1 = (IPluginContribution)c1;
    IPluginContribution pc2 = (IPluginContribution)c2;

    String id1 = pc1.getLocalId().substring(0,3);
    String id2 = pc2.getLocalId().substring(0,3);

    result = id1.compareTo(id2);

    return result;
}
```

Then, in my [WorkbenchAdvisor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor.html), I overrode the [getComparitorFor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor.html#getComparatorFor%28java.lang.String%29) method to instantiate ContributionComparator I created if the contributionType was a property:

```
@Override
public ContributionComparator getComparatorFor(String contributionType) {
    ContributionComparator cc;

    if (contributionType.equals(IContributionService.TYPE_PROPERTY)) {
        cc = new MyContributionComparator();
    } else {
        cc = super.getComparatorFor(contributionType);
    }

    return cc;
}
```

Now the property pages show up in the order I want them to.

Comment: In my plugin I am not subclassing the WorkbenchAdvisor, and would be curios where I make the link between my plugin.xml and the subclass. Do I need a class that implements IApplication and is referenced as an application in the plugin.xml?

Comment: I've tried with implementing IApplication and subclassing the WorkbenchAdvisor, but the application that my team is developing is being launched through a product, not an application. I don't suppose there is another way to do this, considering the project is launched via a product?

Comment: My application is implemented as a product also. My product defines an application.  The `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` is created in the `WorkbenchAdvisor`, which is created in the `IApplication` implementation.  The application is defined in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point of plugin.xml and referenced in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension.  Clear?

Comment: For some reason despite doing as you described I've put a breakpoint in the getComparatorFor method and it seems like it never reaches that. I will look into this issue more thoroughly later though and give you an appropriate answer with all the code included. I must've forgotten something...